# What to do after unzipping the Java EE 7 sdk .zip file?

Tags: java, sdk

I am quite new to Linux. I have been trying to install the Java EE 7 SDk on my ubuntu. I downloaded and unzipped the file "java_ee_sdk-7u1.zip". Which creates another folder named glassfish4 on my downloads directory. What are the next steps??I already have JDK 8 installed on my ubuntu. the JAVA_HOME variable is set at "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle".

Answer (score 2):

What you *should* do next depends on what you want to do. I guess when you want to develop something you surely use [a very good java IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/). In this case, the IDE needs to know the place of your SDK so that it can use the compiler and the libraries. In IDEA, you only need to tell where you unpacked the SDK zip and it sets up everything for you. On my machine, I have all java SDK's in my home directory and the IDEA and it looks like the following

[image]

When you are using another IDE like Netbeans or Eclipse, then the way to tell the IDE about the SDK might be a bit different, but the general approach is the same.